# How I can diagnose why script is not found in aws codeploy? Error: specifies a script with no location value

Tags: amazon-web-services

In my aws codeploy fails because I get the error:

```
[Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 0.02708 0 retries] put_host_command_complete(command_status:"Failed",diagnostics:{format:"JSON",payload:"{\"error_code\":5,\"script_name\":\"\",\"message\":\"The deployment failed because the application specification file specifies a script with no location value. Specify the location in the hooks section of the AppSpec file, and then try again.\",\"log\":\"\"}"},host_command_identifier:"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")
```

This error seen to cause beforeInstall hook to hang with uknown error.
My appspec.yml is:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux

files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html
    overwrite: true
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE

hooks:

  ApplicationStop:
    - location: php /var/www/html/artisan down
      timeout: 300
      runas: www-data
    - location: service nginx down
      runas: root
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: echo "Download Success"
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
      runas: root 
    - location: find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
      runas: root
  
  ApplicationStart:
    - script: /var/www/html/deploy/start_application.sh
      runas: www-data
```

But I cannot extract more info regarding this error. The reason why is because I do not see the failing command. I cannot find out which command in which Hook fails upon me. How I can diagnose the missing command?

As a meant to fix it I tries the following:

```
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: ""
      command: echo "Download Success"
      runas: root
```

But I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to diagnose the problem (getting a different error) is to follow the following guides.

## Step1 Create the Bare minimum appspec.

```
cp appspec.yaml appspec.yaml.bak
```

Then *overwrite* the `appspec.yml` with the following yaml:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux

files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/html

hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
  BeforeInstall:
  AfterInstall: 
  ApplicationStart:
```

## Step2 Deploy

git commit and push the file above

## Step3 keep adding hook scripts till same issue occur.

Either via gettings hooks from `appspec.yaml.bak` one at a time or making new ones step by step.

Do not deploy the changes all together but one at a time. It is a good idea to have small changes instead and multiple deploymens compared to less ones with lots of changes.